# como puedo resolver el siguiente problema de django

Tags: python, django

tengo el siguiente error en django lo que estoy tratando de hacer es poder hacer que las notificaciones se muestren en un submenu algo parecido a instagram pero cuando trato de iniciar session me da ese error
[image: error]

tengo el siguiente codigo en las vistas es de las notificaiones

```
def showNotifications(request):
user = request.user
notifications = Notification.objects.filter(user=user).order_by('-date')

context = {
    'notifications': notifications
}

return context
```

tengo lo siguiente en settings

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'instagram/templates')],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            'direct.views.checkDirect',
            'notifications.views.showNotifications',
        ],
    },
},]
```

y tengo lo siguiente en la template

```
{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
                    {% for notification in notifications %}
                    <div class="box-noti">
                        <div class="noti-a">
                            <img src="{{ notification.sender.profile.picture.url }}" alt="user">
                            <p>A <a href=""><strong>{{notification.sender.username}}</strong></a> le gusto tu foto
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="noti-b">
                            <img src="{{notification.post.picture.url}}" alt="like-picture">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    {% endfor %}
                    {% endif %}
```

como podria correguir el error

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor realiza el [tour] y consulta [ask]. Ten presente que debes tratar de ofrecer un [mcve]. En el código que muestras no se ve nada relacionado con el logout (cierre de sesión) **allí, seguramente, haga falta un bloqueo** para que no pase a buscar notificaciones. Incluye esa parte del código para que quienes traten de ayudarte encuentren elementos significativos.

Answer (score 0):

Estas colocando que te recupere el usuario

```
def showNotifications(request):
user = request.user  #indicando que te recupere el usuario
notifications = Notification.objects.filter(user=user).order_by('-date')

context = {
    'notifications': notifications
}

return context
```

Y en el template

```
{% if request.user.is_authenticated %} #intentas iterar solo si esta autentificado
    {% for notification in notifications %}
    <div class="box-noti">
        <div class="noti-a">
            <img src="{{ notification.sender.profile.picture.url }}" alt="user">
            <p>A <a href=""><strong>{{notification.sender.username}}</strong></a> le gusto tu foto
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="noti-b">
            <img src="{{notification.post.picture.url}}" alt="like-picture">
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Solo le estas indicando si esta autentificado realiza esta iteración y no le estas diciendo que hacer si no esta autentificado así que intenta iterar el usuario anonimo por defecto y te manda el error de que el anonimo no se puede iterar

```
     {% endfor %}
   {% elif %}
       #aqui poner una imagen o el link para login para que no intente iterar el anonimo
{% endif %}
```

Coloca un elif y coloca una imagen, boton con el login o en determinado momento que no haga ninguna acción.

Comment: Tengo una duda, por eso no te he dado aún tu (+1) OP dice que el fallo ocurre al cerrar sesión. No indica que lo haya habido antes de iniciarla; y para estar loggeado se debe haber ingresado antes como anónimo (al sitio) y solicitar el formulario de login. Esto corresponde a la situación que describes. ¿Cómo explicas que no se indique fallo en ese contexto? **presumo**, ojalá me equivoque, que falta algo más.

Comment: no osea no me deja iniciar session osea desde el principio

Comment: A mi parecer no te deja iniciar sesión ya que entrando inmediatamente al template empieza a leer el código y encuentra la iteracion (si te logueas desde admin) y entras al template no debería de haber problema para entrar a ese template o si no te deja iniciar sesión desde un template de login o desde admin tendría que haber otro problema

Answer (score 0):

La vistas en Django te permiten acceder al usuario por medio del objeto `request.user` sin importar si este esta autenticado o no, el proceso de autenticación se realiza por cada petición por medio de un [middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/middleware/) , este middleware básicamente lo que hace es revisar si tu petición contiene alguna información que le ayude a saber a quien pertenece esa petición, esto solo aplica si el usuario hizó login anteriormente.

En caso de que el middleware no encuentre una forma de vincular la petición con algún usuario(tal vez no ha hecho login), este agregara una instancia del modelo `AnonymousUser` al campo `request.user`, este objeto no es realmente una instancia de un usuario de tu base de datos, es una abstracción que denota que esa petición no pertenece a alguien autenticado.

Cuando tu haces uso de la propiedad `request.user.is_authenticated` realmente lo que estas haciendo es verificar que el objeto `request.user` no sea una instancia de la clase `AnonymousUser`. Regresando un poco  a tu vista:

```py
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import loader

def showNotifications(request):
    notifications = []

    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        notifications = Notification.objects.filter(user=request.user).order_by('-date')

    context = {
        'notifications': notifications
    }
    
    # Render de plantilla
    template = loader.get_template('RutaPlantilla.html')
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

La primera modificación seria verificar que realmente la instancia de la propiedad `request.user` sea una instancia de tu modelo de Usuarios, esto se verifica a través de la propiedad `request.user.is_authenticated`. Esta acción es la que posiblemente te generaba el error, al no estar haciendo esta validación, es posible que la petición tuviera una instancia de la clase `AnonymousUser` y al intetar hacer una query con él no tuviera mucho sentido por que realmente no es un instancia de un modelo que represente un registro en tu base de datos.

La segunda modificación es el retorno de tu respuesta. Es necesario renderizar el template y retornar el resultado dentro de un objeto `HttpResponse`. La forma que te mostre es la versión larga, realmente Django ofrece un shortcut que simplifica el cargar, renderizar y formar un objeto HttpResponse en un solo paso a través de la función `render`. Este seria el resultado.

```py
from django.shortcuts import render

def showNotifications(request):
    notifications = []

    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        notifications = Notification.objects.filter(user=request.user).order_by('-date')

    context = {
        'notifications': notifications
    }
    
    # Render de plantilla
    return render(request, 'RutaPlantilla.html', context)
```

Por último solo remarcar que la `RutaPlantilla` no hace referencia a la ruta absoluta o relativa a la cual generalmente se esta acostumbrado. Django sigue ciertos parametros para resolver esta ruta que dependen de su configuración, por defecto esta ruta se busca a partir de los directorios `templates` contenido en cada app.